# Upload file with php to another php server

Tags: php

I'm not asking about uploading a file from a browser to a php script, there's plenty of tutorials about that already. I'm asking about this:

I have a php script that has accepted a file from the user, and the file is currently on the hard disk of server 1. I want to upload the file from server 1 to a php script on server 2, using the regular Http post protocol, so the php script on server 2 can be written as a standard file-upload handler.

I cannot find any tutorial on the internet, because they all talk about browser->server1. The tutorials about php upload all talk about ftp, but I don't want to use that protocol.

Please help?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use CURL for this. Something like this should do it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@/path/to/file.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server2/upload.php');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can then handle the the server2 part as a regular file upload. See [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) for more information on those options.

Comment: I just needed this again for another project, and I made an error in my new code that was so subtle I had to post it here: it is _very_ important that the CURLOPT_POST,true is BEFORE the POSTFIELDS when that is set to an array!

Answer (score 9):

You could use SOAP to send the file from one server to the other.

Receiving server:

```
<?php
$server = new Soap_Server( null, array('uri'=>'somerui') );
$server->addFunction( 'receiveFile' );
function receiveFile( $file ) {
   file_put_contents( 'somepath', base64_decode( $file ) );
}
?>
```

Sending server:

```
<?php
$client = new Soap_Client( null, array('uri'=>'somerui') );
$client->receiveFile( base64_encode( file_get_contents( 'somepath' ) );
?>
```

Comment: Hehe, a plus one for originality :-)

Comment: I wrote this years ago, I was still pretty new. Now I shudder in horror that I suggested this. Use the accepted answer.

Comment: No worries, I didn't use it, but it was original as I said :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need two Scripts.

First script that will in way emulate browser behavior, it will take a file and send it to seconds script, that will handles it just like regular file upload script.

My guess you have to use "http_post_fields" for the first script, it seems to handle files.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-fields.php

Good Luck.