# Upload images to a different domain

Tags: php, upload, dns

Let's assume that i have 2 domains running on the same server, www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com.
I will use www.domain1.com for data transfer. basically this domain will form my website.
I would like to use www.domain2.com as my imageserver.

let's say the ftp structure looks like this:
(i hope this structure will come out readable, since i used alt[255] to space it. however, if it doesn't come out readable, is there a way to use emptyspace characters in SO?)

> domains
>   |
>   +-- domain1.com
>   |     |
>   |     +-- public_html
>   |
>   +-- domain1.com
>         |
>         +-- public_html

is there a way for me to upload images from www.domain1.com to www.domain2.com in php?

Comment: You can use the file manipulation functions in PHP, assuming that the PHP has access to both domain directories.

Comment: might be [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135787/upload-file-with-php-to-another-php-server)

Comment: you mean i just should use something like move_uploaded_file(domain1.com/public_html/tmp, ../../domain2.com/public_html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<pre><code>
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../domain2.com/';
$d = dir($dir);
echo "Handle: " . $d->handle . "\n";
echo "Path: " . $d->path . "\n";
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   echo $entry."\n";
}
$d->close();
</code>
</pre>
```

You can try the obove code. When you get the list, you can handle your uploads by

```
    $dest_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../domain2.com/YOURSTOREFOLDER/'
    $filename = 'hello_world.jpg';
    move_upload_file($uploadFileName,$dest_dir.$filename);
```

Comment: after i set the permissions of the domain2.com folder to 755, the reasult actually showed content. thank you for your info, i will have a go at this.
*edit*
i figured that 755 wouldn't be safe, so i set it back to 711 and tested on a subfolder of domain2.com. i got a result on that too.