# how to open txt file from another server using php

Tags: php

I want to open and write a txt file from another server, but I don't know how to do it?  Can anyone help me?

```html
<?PHP
   $fname=$_POST["fname"];

   $groupid=$_POST["groupid"];
   $myfile = fopen("Ji.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, $fname."|".$groupid."\r\n");
   fclose($myfile)
?>
```

I want to replace Ji.txt with http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/ddd.txt

Comment: You'll have to use FTP or something similar to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can do it with the FTP functions

```
<?php
// Connect to remote FTP server
$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com")or die("Cant connect to ftp server");
$login = ftp_login($conn, "username", "password");

// Open local (temporary) file handle
$fh = fopen("Ji.txt", "a+");

// Get remote file and save it to the previous file handle
if(ftp_fget($conn, $fh, "Ji.txt", FTP_ASCII))
{
    // Local file has now been updated with the content of the remote Ji.txt
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $groupid = $_POST['groupid'];
    fwrite($fh, $fname.'|'.$groupid.'\r\n');
    if(ftp_fput($conn, "Ji.txt", $fh, FTP_ASCII))
        echo 'File saved to remote server';
    else
        echo 'Error saving to remote server';
}
else
    echo 'Error downloading remote file';

ftp_close($conn);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Read more about ftp_fput etc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php

Comment: I've updated the code as the original code only did a write operation to the remote server. The updated code first retrieves remote file, then appends the $_POST variables and then upload it to remote server.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the files over HTTP by using `fopen` or `cURL`.

You can't write to files over HTTP unless the server you are writing to is set up to understand an appropriate request. You could configure it to support [`PUT` requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) (make sure you have some kind of authn/authz system in place!) and make one using `cURL`.

Alternatively, you could use some other protocol to make the file available between servers (such as NFS).

Answer (score 0):

As long as [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is set to True you can pass an URL to `fopen()` and read the data. Writing however, is impossible. However, you can write a wrapper around the file that accepts both GET & POSTS requests. A GET returns the contents of the file and a POST (or PUT) saves content to the files. The downside of this is that you must add security and it's a lot more complex to save the data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the other server and the text file is available at a web address (ie you can see it in a browser) then you can use fopen to grab it, make your edits or whatever and then post back to a script that will handle the post data and save the file using curl. Example code below copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135787/upload-file-with-php-to-another-php-server)

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@/path/to/file.txt'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server2/upload.php');
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Posting** server should be something like this

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('ourfilename' =>'yourpath/test.txt'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://urlreceivepost/getfile.php');
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Then **getfile.php** at your above url

```
if ($_POST) {
$file= $_POST['ourfilename'];
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$new = 'test.txt';
file_put_contents($new, $data);
var_dump($new);}
```