# Technically possible to change OpenCart upload folder to other server?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, opencart, opencart2.x

It is technically possible in OpenCart 2.0 to change upload folder,  where customers can upload files? Basically it is defined in config.php (both in root and admin folder) like this:

```
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/www/shop/system/upload/');
```

It is possible simple change that destination (for example to another server)?

Currently i'm using this code (simply modified catalog/.../product/product.tpl):

```
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'file') { ?>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                      <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <?php echo $button_upload; ?>
                    </button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $button_upload; ?></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body embed-responsive">
                            <iframe height="300px"  width="350px" frameborder="0" class="embed-responsive-item" src="captcha/captcha.php"></iframe>                 
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
                          </div>              
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

After success captcha, runs this index.php in iframe (ran on other server, which is a network attached storage with fix IP):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php?new_upload=true" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"> 
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['new_upload'])) {
    upload();
}

function upload() {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0; break;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0; break;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($fileType != "jpg" && $fileType != "png" && $fileType != "jpeg" && $fileType != "pdf" && $fileType != "JPG" && $fileType != "JPEG" && $fileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0; break;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded."; break;
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            chmod($target_file, 0777); //change permission
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This working fine, and you can easily upload files to server, but i look for a better solution. This didnt connect the order and the uploaded file, like opencart normally do.

Comment: _“(for example to another server)”_ – that is rather not a “for example” thing, but changes the scope of the question _completely_. Normally, file uploads are only processed within the file system of the server that the script runs upon – and having the files transferred from there to a different server will most likely _not_ work by simply modifying the value of that constant, but is more likely to require more profound modifications to the code that actually handles uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work, but you have to keep in mind some things.

1. The folder should he there.
2. The folder should have appropriate permissions.

It would work fine.

Comment: It may be possible with CURL library.

Comment: Please see the following link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135787/upload-file-with-php-to-another-php-server