# Upload and manage user uploads on multiple servers

Tags: php, server, filesystems

I am creating a website which will allow users to upload few images and other files (mainly zip) which can be publicly accessible (user can share url). I want to store files on different servers. Like firsthost.tld/path-to-file/name.ext and secondhist.tld/path-to-file/name.ext
For some reasons i want to use different server, i want php to handle file upload and distribution across servers. Also i don't require shadow copies of images on multiple server. I want different images to be on different servers. I can store server id and file path in database to retrieve filepath.

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: How to archive this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135814/2862130 that suggests tu use cURL. Here is the official documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.

In your PHP script that handle the form treatment you should implement a logic to distribute your files across your servers. For instance every day you upload to a different server, but it depends on the traffic you will have in order to not overload one server in comparison to the other ones.

You should put in the servers you are uploading to a script to receive the files that are sent to them. Here is an Example provided by the PHP documentation to implement the server sive logic : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php.

Using cloud storage services could also be a solution that requires less time to implement.